# NFS share from windows server fail to mount on linux

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, nfs

I setup a nfs share on a Windows Server 2012 R2,
I have tried several different configurations (authentications, share permissions etc) but linux client keep getting error with invalid arguments.

```
root@docker:~# mount -vvv -t nfs mycloud:/CLOUD /mnt/cloud
mount.nfs: timeout set for Wed Jun 13 18:09:44 2018
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'vers=4,addr=10.10.11.100,clientaddr=10.10.11.26'
mount.nfs: mount(2): Protocol not supported
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'addr=10.10.11.100'
mount.nfs: prog 100003, trying vers=3, prot=6
mount.nfs: trying 10.10.11.100 prog 100003 vers 3 prot TCP port 2049
mount.nfs: prog 100005, trying vers=3, prot=17
mount.nfs: trying 10.10.11.100 prog 100005 vers 3 prot UDP port 2049
mount.nfs: mount(2): Invalid argument
mount.nfs: an incorrect mount option was specified
root@docker:~#
```

Comment: have you installed nfs-client on system before mapping/mounting

Comment: what do you mean? the server side also need nfs-client? the client side already install the latest version of nfs-common package, otherwise `-t nfs` cant even use.

Comment: i solved the problem by mounting it with `-o vers=4.1`, how can i close this question now?

Comment: you can answer this question and close it by ticking it on the left side after answering